# Mobile website html element too wide

Tags: css, mobile, width

I'm designing a mobile version of my website, which should be like a mobile application.

The problem is that there is a strange width to my html element in my mobile browser. I have tried setting body and html to width:480px; and the content is 480px but even then there is a lot of whitespace next to the content (estimated at about 300px). The effect of this is also that the website is not zoomed to the content but to the content + the whitespace and you first have to zoom in to properly use the website.

Ofcourse I want to use width:100%; so it renders well on different screen sizes.

Does anyone know what's going on or how to fix it?

**Edit** 
The html code is just straightforward xhtml transitional, nothing special. In the css I have:

```
body, html {
width:480px !important;}
```

But if I would not set a width to those it should work right? I also don't set a width for any other elements (other than like buttons 100px and things like that) and if I view the mobile version on my computer no elements seem to be wider than the body.

Comment: Could you include some code? Maybe an example in jsfiddle?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Have you add the `viewport` meta tag ?

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
```

Comment: I was not looking for this command specifically. I thought it was a style sheet issue. I put the command in and bang. fixes my wide body with scroll bars to fit the actual width of my page.