# Page dimension bigger than actual device screen

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I have this simple HTML generated from React

```
<!doctype html>
<html><head><title data-react-helmet="true"></title><style type="text/css" data-styled-components="" data-styled-components-is-local="true"></style></head><body><div id="app"><div data-reactroot="">Hello</div></div></body></html>
```

When I open it in Chrome with mobile view, the page dimension is bigger than screen size. In this example, the iPhone 5 dimension is 320x568 but my page width is already 980px. There is no CSS used on the

[image]

This forces me to use bigger font size which looks normal on that page but becomes really big on desktop. How the page size can be bigger than screen size? How's that happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5582046/mobile-website-html-element-too-wide), simply adding meta tag for viewport

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is the @media selector. You read more about it [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp).

At the bottom of your code (or anywhere you like, but it's bet to put it at the bottom), you'd add

```
@media only screen and (max-width: ##px) {

}
```

Where you see "##", you'd put the max-width of the phone screens you're trying to display code in.

On the inside of the brackets, you can rewrite your entire website to fit specifically to a phone (and it'd only show up on a phone with a max-width of ##px or less), or you can simply edit one thing, such as the font-size in this post.

Say for instance in your primary post you had

```
.desktop {
font-size: 30px;
}
```

For phone, you'd put

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 568px) {
.desktop {
font-size: 15px;
}
}
```

I hope this helps out! If so, don't forget to upvote and mark as acceptable.

Comment: Hey I don't know if using media query to determine the font size will help because the main issue is the actual HTML document is already bigger than screen size. And it does ruin media query like if I query for mobile size 568px, it does not recognise it because the screen size above is 980px. I am wondering how that could happen.

Comment: @spondbob Ohh, I'm sorry. I must have misread your question. I'll look more closely at your question and get back to you if I find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

There are pages in the website that require reworking, such as converting everything to a single vertical column for mobile screens. In the React Native EditScreenInfo title_uri, I added a query string: mob=yes. The value isn't important, but the server code uses it to determine if it's called from a mobile device. So the server code determines which layout is to be used. I also used JavaScript to make the text as big as possible in the various tags for mobile.